# URL not working ASP MVC in SMS function

Tags: asp.net, datatable, paging

I am working on a reset password function where the new link to reset the password is going to be sent by SMS. But when the URL link is genereted and send to the mobile number it is not clickable for some reason. I have checked around a little and i have seen that it could be android specific. Any suggestions?

```
var link = _urlProvider.ToAbsoluteUrl(Url.Action("VerifySmsCode", "Account", new { enteredCode = code }));

        var body = string.Format("Verifiera ditt telefonnumer via följande länk: " +
            Environment.NewLine + " {0} ",
            link);

        _smsGateway.Send(Installation.Name, body, Buyer.Msisdn.Value);

        ViewBag.Message = "Ett SMS med verifieringskod har skickats";
```

This is my code for the function. The link is generated correctly but it is not clickable in android phones?

```
public string ToAbsoluteUrl(string relative)
    {
        var request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
        return string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}", (request.IsSecureConnection) ? "https" : "http",
            request.Url.Host, (request.Url.Port == 80) ? "" : ":" + request.Url.Port.ToString(),
            VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(relative));
    }
```

Comment: i think sending link via SMS is not a good idea.As you may not know your target audience Smartphone abilities (or not having smartphone itself). A better option would be One Time Password or similar which will also be System Agnostic .Also remember SMS is for short text and on older phones your URLs will break(160 chars).

Comment: Okey but in out configuration we have decided to go for that implementation so we're going to stick with that. Back to the question, do you know a solution for my problem? Because the link works fine on Iphone but not on android.

Comment: No sorry that didnt help me at all.